# Buscar char(13) o (10) en un campo y remplazarlo por un enter

Tags: c#, oracle

Genere esta variable que traigo de la base de datos pero en la misma hay char(13) o char(10) entonces lo que quiero es crear un buscador donde encuentre estos dos caracteres y lo convierta en otra cadena para que forme otra linea de mi dirección.

`sAddress        = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["STREET_INFO"].ToString();`

Comment: No comprendo lo que quieres, en Windows, `enter` es char(13) + char(10), en linux es char(10). ¿cuál es tu problema?. ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de la entrada que tienes y la salida que buscas?

Comment: Lo que dijo @jachguate: en realidad estás pidiendo (en el título) reemplazar un enter por un enter. No tiene sentido. ¿Puedes aclarar?

Comment: @jachguate `enter` es `char(13)`; el salto de línea viene definido por `enter` + `new line` (que es `char(10)`). De hecho creo que lo que quiere es reemplazar el salto de línea por sólo `enter`.

Comment: @SJuan76, creo que me he expresado mal, tratando de corregir: Hay dos caracteres especiales (que existen por razones históricas): Retorno de carro **CR** (decimal 13) y salto de línea **LF** (decimal 10).  Enter (la tecla) produce un Retorno de Carro (13). En Windows, el _salto de línea_ se representa por la secuencia CRLF, en linux por LF y en Mac por CR. La tecla enter efectivamente produce solamente un CR, pero este normalmente es _traducido_ a la secuencia de _salto de línea_ de acuerdo a lo mencionado en la cultura de cada sistema operativo.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes revisar si en tu cadena están contenidos y realizar el reemplazo, los reemplazos equivalentes son:

> ```
> chr(13) => "\r"  ... retorno de carro.
> chr(10) => "\n"  ... nueva línea.
> ```

por lo tanto sería de esta forma:

```
            if (sAddress.Contains((char)13)) 
            {
                sAddress = sAddress.Replace("\r", "<texto_remplazo>");
            }
            if (sAddress.Contains((char)10))
            {
                sAddress = sAddress.Replace("\n", "<texto_remplazo>");
            }
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
 String sAddress = "Hola soy StackOverflow.com  " + ((char)13) + " buna " + ((char)10) + " StackOverflow.com";

            if (sAddress.Contains((char)13))
            {
                sAddress = sAddress.Replace("\r", "aquisecambio13");
            }
            if (sAddress.Contains((char)10))
            {
                sAddress = sAddress.Replace("\n", "aquisecambio10");
            }
```

Donde tendrías como resultado:

```
Hola soy StackOverflow.com  aquisecambio13 buna aquisecambio10 StackOverflow.com
```

Comment: Gracias, aqui lo optimize un poco mas                 if (sAddress.Contains((char)13)|sAddress.Contains((char)10)) 
                { 
                    str1 = sAddress.Substring(0,sAddress.IndexOf((char)13));
                    str2 = sAddress.Substring(sAddress.IndexOf((char)13) + 1,            sAddress.Length);

                }         else       {
                    str1 = string.Empty;
                    str2 = string.Empty;
                }

Answer (score 2):

Sí lo quieres reemplazar por un "Enter", asumo que es por un salto de línea, esto ya se había respondido en StackOverflow en inglés, el la pregunta [How to replace part of string by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015593/how-to-replace-part-of-string-by-position)(¿Cómo reemplazar parte de un string por la posición?)

Lo que dice es que debes de usar un [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

```
sAddress = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["STREET_INFO"].ToString();
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(sAddress);
aStringBuilder.Remove(10, 1); // (index, largo)
aStringBuilder.Insert(10, "\n"); //insertas
aStringBuilder.Remove(13, 1); // (index, largo)
aStringBuilder.Insert(13, "\n"); //insertas
theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```